# Closing Smart App Banner in iOS Appium test

Tags: ios, selenium, appium

I'm testing a website using Appium for iOS.  The site has an associated app and uses Apple's [Smart App Banners](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/PromotingAppswithAppBanners/PromotingAppswithAppBanners.html) to promote the app.  I'd like to test for the presence of the banner and close it at the beginning of my Appium test, but the banner doesn't appear to exist in the DOM.  Is there any way to do this, short of mousing around with a pixel location?

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch to native context:

```
driver.context("NATIVE_APP");
```

and check if it contains banner, for quick investigation you can print to console result of `driver.getPageSource()`